# JavaFX: Allow window resizing in one direction only

Tags: java, javafx, window

One can change the resizeable state of a JavaFX stage using [javafx.stage.Stage.setResizable(boolean)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#setResizable-boolean-) method.

---

**QUESTION**

Is there any possibility to allow resize only horizontally or only vertically?

---

There are methods like `Stage.setMaxWidth`, `Stage.setMaxHeight`, `Stage.setMinWidth`, `Stage.setMinHeight` but they can only be used to control resizing with fixed sized stages (by setting `width = minWidth = maxWidth`  for example, to disallow horizontal resizing).

Comment: What do you mean by "but they only work well with fixed sized stages"?

Comment: @M.S. See the update.

Comment: You mean it will work only if you have a predefined fixed width?

Comment: @M.S. Yes .............

Comment: Is the initial width ok in your case? I mean do you want to keep the initial width after the stage is initialized?

Comment: @M.S. The content of the stage is dynamic, and the width/height resizes accordingly. I want **the user** not to be allowed to resize in only one direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prevent external attempts to change height like this:

```java
stage.show();
stage.maxHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
stage.minHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
```

Same for width:

```java
stage.maxWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
stage.minWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());
```

This way will give you the ability to resize it internally when the content changes (call `sizeToScene()` for example).